# How to improve stylesheet.min.css loading time in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, optimization, plugins, waterfall

Recently have made the website and used `WP Fastest Cache` and `Clearfy` plugins to optimize loading speed.

The waterfall indexes become much better, but still are problem with **stylesheet.min.css**, it still is too long.

How I can to reduce it's time?

Website waterfall image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant see your website so just few recommendations.

1. you can use gzip compression if your server support it
2. you can try use some CDN service to speed up delivery of your files
3. you can try to remove unnecessary parts of you stylesheet.min.css

(off topic you can try to lower the number of your website requests - 146 is quite a lot)